# Change cursor to wait when opening another stage JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, stage

I want to change te cursor to wait when the user open a new stage this stage is only for taking a snapshot and then open this snapshot in the default system program for images, this normally  takes like 10 secons whitch is not much but it hinders the user experience.

this is my code for the calling of the new stage where i try to change the cursor

```
public void imprimirConsulta(){
    //change the cursor to wait
    stage.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
    //crate a task for a new thread
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               /*take from a tableview row the object 
                 that has the information for the new stage*/ 
               consul = tvConsulta.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
               //launch the new stage
               hEstadistica.ImpreConsul(true, consul);
            }
        });
        return null;
      }
    };
    //when finish the task change the cursor to the default style
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        stage.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
      }
    });
    //star the new thread
    Thread tt = new Thread(task);
    tt.setDaemon(true);
    tt.start();
}
```

the new stage close immediately whit this code

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
        delay.setOnFinished( event -> stage.hide());
        delay.play();
}
```

the snapshot is take whit this code

```
WritableImage snapshot = stage.getScene().snapshot(null);
        File file = new File("src//HE//Utilidades//Imagenes//consul.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null), "png", file);
            Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
            dt.open(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm working with files FXML, the new stage when loads make a SQL query to a embedded SQLite databese, but it is very simple and only text is involved, the event is launch from a ContextMenu in the TableView, the stage is show and the snapshot image is open with the default system program but the cursor doesn't change.

How can I make the cursor change state?

Comment: Why does what not work? Please be more precise in your question.

Comment: i what to make the cursor change during the wait of 10 secons and then the cursor change to the orginal form, the code above is missing something because the cursor remains the same